# Stream Filter == List.get(index) não compila

Tags: java, filter, stream, map

Estou tentando criar uma `Stream` para filtrar uma lista de uma classe com diversos atributos. Um destes atributos se repete em outras instâncias. Estou tentando filtrar estes membros de instancia para fazer uma soma de um dos atributos da classe.

```
public class InsumoTratado {

private Long codigoComposicao;
private String textoCodigoComposicao;
private String descricaoComposicao;
private String unidadeComposicao;
private String tipoItem;
private Long codigoItem;
private String descricaoItemComposicao;
private String unidadeItem;
private double quantidadeComposicao;
private double valorUnitario;



public InsumoTratado() {
    }


public InsumoTratado(Long codigoComposicao, String textoCodigoComposicao, String descricaoComposicao, String unidadeComposicao, String tipoItem,
        Long codigoItem, String descricaoItemComposicao, String unidadeItem, double quantidadeComposicao,
        double valorUnitario) {
    super();
    this.codigoComposicao = codigoComposicao;
    this.textoCodigoComposicao = textoCodigoComposicao;
    this.descricaoComposicao = descricaoComposicao;
    this.unidadeComposicao = unidadeComposicao;
    this.tipoItem = tipoItem;
    this.codigoItem = codigoItem;
    this.descricaoItemComposicao = descricaoItemComposicao;
    this.unidadeItem = unidadeItem;
    this.quantidadeComposicao = quantidadeComposicao;
    this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
}


public Long getCodigoComposicao() {
    return codigoComposicao;
}


public void setCodigoComposicao(Long codigoComposicao) {
    this.codigoComposicao = codigoComposicao;
}

public String getTextoCodigoComposicao() {
    return textoCodigoComposicao;
}


public void setTextoCodigoComposicao(String textoCodigoComposicao2) {
    this.textoCodigoComposicao = String.valueOf((getCodigoComposicao()));
}


public String getDescricaoComposicao() {
    return descricaoComposicao;
}


public void setDescricaoComposicao(String descricaoComposicao) {
    this.descricaoComposicao = descricaoComposicao;
}


public String getUnidadeComposicao() {
    return unidadeComposicao;
}


public void setUnidadeComposicao(String unidadeComposicao) {
    this.unidadeComposicao = unidadeComposicao;
}


public String getTipoItem() {
    return tipoItem;
}


public void setTipoItem(String tipoItem) {
    this.tipoItem = tipoItem;
}


public Long getCodigoItem() {
    return codigoItem;
}


public void setCodigoItem(Long codigoItem) {
    this.codigoItem = codigoItem;
}


public String getDescricaoItemComposicao() {
    return descricaoItemComposicao;
}


public void setDescricaoItemComposicao(String descricaoItemComposicao) {
    this.descricaoItemComposicao = descricaoItemComposicao;
}


public String getUnidadeItem() {
    return unidadeItem;
}


public void setUnidadeItem(String unidadeItem) {
    this.unidadeItem = unidadeItem;
}


public double getQuantidadeComposicao() {
    return quantidadeComposicao;
}


public void setQuantidadeComposicao(double quantidadeComposicao) {
    this.quantidadeComposicao = quantidadeComposicao;
}


public double getValorUnitario() {
    return valorUnitario;
}


public void setValorUnitario(double valorUnitario) {
    this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
}


    
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "InsumoTratado [codigoComposicao=" + codigoComposicao 
            + ", descricaoComposicao=" + descricaoComposicao
            + ", unidadeComposicao=" + unidadeComposicao 
            + ", tipoItem=" + tipoItem 
            + ", codigoItem=" + codigoItem
            + ", descricaoItemComposicao=" + descricaoItemComposicao 
            + ", unidadeItem=" + unidadeItem
            + ", quantidadeComposicao=" + quantidadeComposicao 
            + ", valorUnitario=" + valorUnitario + "]";
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((codigoComposicao == null) ? 0 : codigoComposicao.hashCode());
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    InsumoTratado other = (InsumoTratado) obj;
    if (codigoComposicao == null) {
        if (other.codigoComposicao != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigoComposicao.equals(other.codigoComposicao))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public class MainProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonSyntaxException, JsonIOException, FileNotFoundException {

    //Declaração das Classes a serem utilizadas na aplicação principal
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Formatador formatador = new Formatador();
    InsumoTratado iTratado = new InsumoTratado();
    List<InsumoTratado> ListaInsumos2 = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        //Import do arquivo Json com os dados dos insumos e armazenamento dos valores em um array de dados no formato String
        Insumo[] insumo1 = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("C://Users//marco//OneDrive//Área de Trabalho//file.txt"),Insumo[].class);

        // Instanciação dos elementos coletados do arquivo Json e armazenamento em uma nova lista tratada, com dados tipo Long e String
        for (Insumo x : insumo1) {
            Long codigoComposicao = x.getCodigoComposicao();
            String textoCodigoComposicao = x.getTextoCodigoComposicao();
            String descricaoComposicao = x.getDescricaoComposicao();
            String unidadeComposicao = x.getUnidadeComposicao();
            String tipoItem = x.getTipoItem();
            Long codigoItem = Long.parseLong(x.getCodigoItem());
            String descricaoItemComposicao = x.getDescricaoItemComposicao();
            String unidadeItem = x.getUnidadeItem();
            Double quantidadeComposicao = formatador.converterVirgulaParaPonto((x.getQuantidadeComposicao()));
            Double valorUnitario = formatador.converterVirgulaParaPonto((x.getValorUnitario()));
            iTratado = new InsumoTratado(codigoComposicao, textoCodigoComposicao, descricaoComposicao,
                    unidadeComposicao, tipoItem, codigoItem, descricaoItemComposicao, unidadeItem,
                    quantidadeComposicao, valorUnitario);
            iTratado.setCodigoComposicao(codigoComposicao);
            iTratado.setTextoCodigoComposicao(textoCodigoComposicao);
            iTratado.setDescricaoComposicao(descricaoComposicao);
            iTratado.setUnidadeComposicao(unidadeComposicao);
            iTratado.setTipoItem(tipoItem);
            iTratado.setCodigoItem(codigoItem);
            iTratado.setDescricaoItemComposicao(descricaoItemComposicao);
            iTratado.setUnidadeItem(unidadeItem);
            iTratado.setQuantidadeComposicao(quantidadeComposicao);
            iTratado.setValorUnitario(valorUnitario);
            ListaInsumos2.add(iTratado);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Filtro para remover valores repetidos de descricao dos Códigos de Composição
    List<Long> listIter = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> deDupStringList3 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (InsumoTratado y : ListaInsumos2) {
        y.getCodigoComposicao();
        listIter.add(y.getCodigoComposicao());
        deDupStringList3 = listIter.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    Long index = deDupStringList3.get(0);
    Long index1 = deDupStringList3.get(1);
    Long index2 = deDupStringList3.get(2);
    Long index3 = deDupStringList3.get(3);
    Long index4 = deDupStringList3.get(4);

    
    //Filtro e construção da saída do arquivo no console
    Stream<InsumoTratado> st1 = ListaInsumos2.stream();
    Double total = st1.filter(p -> p.getCodigoComposicao().equals(index))

            .mapToDouble(p -> p.getValorUnitario() * p.getQuantidadeComposicao()).sum();

    System.out.println(ListaInsumos2.get(0).getCodigoComposicao().toString() + " "
            + ListaInsumos2.get(0).getDescricaoComposicao().toString() + " "
            + ListaInsumos2.get(0).getUnidadeComposicao().toString() + " " + String.format("%.2f", total));

}
```

Criei essa stream:

```
Stream<Insumo> st1 = lista.stream();
               st1.filter(p -> p.getCodigoComposicao() == "94793")
              .mapToDouble(p -> p.getValorUnitario() * p.getQuantidadeComposicao()).sum();
```

Esse `"94793"` é como se fosse uma chave para os outros elementos, mas quando tento colocar algo como:

```
Stream<Insumo> st1 = lista.stream();
               st1.filter(p -> p.getCodigoComposicao() == List<Insumo>.getCodigo)
              .mapToDouble(p -> p.getValorUnitario() * p.getQuantidadeComposicao()).sum();


Stream<InsumoTratado> st2 = ListaInsumos2.stream();
        Double total2 = st2.filter(p -> p.getCodigoComposicao().equals(index1))
                .mapToDouble(p -> p.getValorUnitario() * p.getQuantidadeComposicao()).sum();
```

Ele só retorna o último elemento da lista, e não a soma dos valores, como a `Stream` anterior faz.

Tentei também utilizar o Filter.equals, mas também só consigo avaliar um item por vez. O que eu estou tentando implementar é: Receber uma lista de índices de um List e passar esse índice como uma espécie de chave para a stream iterar sobre a lista para calcular automaticamente as somas de cada uma das notas fiscais que recebi inicialmente.

Como posso resolver isso?

---

Estou usando uma nova abordagem, utilizando dois loops para poder pegar os valores de uma lista que me passa os numeros das notas fiscais, e os uso como filtro para calcular as somas.

```
List<Long> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

        indexes.add(94793L);
        indexes.add(98561L);
        indexes.add(87286L);
        indexes.add(88830L);
        indexes.add(88831L);

        double sum = 0;

        for (int j = indexes.indexOf(indexes.get(0)); j < indexes.size(); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaInsumos2.size(); i++) {

                InsumoTratado insumo = ListaInsumos2.get(i);
                if (insumo.getCodigoComposicao().equals(indexes.get(j))) {

                    sum = (sum + insumo.getPrecoFinal());
```

Estou conseguindo obter os valores, mas somados em uma única variável. Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa soma filtrando por índice, também?

Comment: Vc pode postar mais da sua classe `Insumo`, principalmente esse método `getCodigo`?

Comment: Postei a classe completa e também a aplicação para se ter uma idéia da implementação inicial.

Comment: O que não da pra entender é esse `List<Insumo>.getCodigo`. Ta rodando assim? E esse número "94793" vai variar ou vai ser sempre esse?

Answer (score -2):

getCodigo está recuperando um código de nota fiscal que veio em um arquivo externo. Esse valor vai variar, pois existem varios códigos em uma lista